# Strange comment indentation results

Tags: indentation, major-mode, comment, emacs26

I am working with a simple major mode. The format has one single line comment delimiter, i.e., `%`. However, I get strange results when running `fill-paragraph` on a comment. Specifically, the result I see when running `fill-paragraph` on the first line of the following comment

```
% 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
% 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
```

is

```
% 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
%  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
%  27
```

Observe how the next line is indented by one more space. I expect `fill-paragraph` to not change the comment at all. If I were to run `fill-paragraph` again on the second line of this resultant comment the third line is preceded, following the `%`, by yet another space.

I am looking for a way to change the major mode such that this "cascading" behavior no longer occurs when `fill-paragraph` is called on a comment.

UPDATE 1

I have verified that the issue is related to the particular major mode I am using. Specifically, I started emacs using `emacs -Q`, loaded the major mode manually, and then enabled the major mode. After doing this, the "cascading" behavior was exhibited again.

The major mode I am using can be found here: https://github.com/abella-prover/abella/blob/master/emacs/abella.el

UPDATE 2

Following @JeanPierre's comment regarding emacs 25. I have confirmed that this behavior does not occur in emacs 25 but DOES occur in emacs 26.

Comment: Is your major mode derived from `prog-mode`?

Comment: Please provide more info: what major mode, for example? And do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the linked file (emacs 25.1.1).  It does behave as it should.